# Streaming data out of Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer

There is enough ADX documentation available about streaming ingestion but I don't find anything about streaming it out of Kusto. Even continuous export has minimum limit on export frequency (I think 5 mins) and that is far from being a streaming method of exporting. Is there a way to stream high volume data out of ADX to BLOB or ADLS Gen2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuous export is the recommended approach for continuously exporting high volume of data from Kusto since the exporting is distributed. The minimal frequency is one minute, see the "frequency" section in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/continuous-data-export) :
[image]

For other exports of a large amount of data, use the applicable method in the SDKs. For example, here is the [Java SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-java/blob/d6075a252e8fea0b8bb590cabf0924af2b018106/data/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/kusto/data/ClientImpl.java#L166) and here is the .Net sample:

```
KustoConnectionStringBuilder kcsb = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
kcsb.Streaming = true;

using (KustoDataContext context = new KustoDataContext(kcsb))
using (var reader = context.ExecuteQuery(query, requestProperties: requestProperties))
using (var csvStream = new CsvFromDataReaderJitStream(reader, leaveOpen: false, writeHeader: true))
{
  // consume stream here
}
```

Comment: Isn't there corresponding .NET example? I am not able to find this , I am ideally looking for .NET SDK option for doing this.

Comment: I updated my response with a .Net example

Comment: so there is no command (kusto) counterpart of this SDK code I believe?

Comment: Yes, in .Net it is different than Java

Comment: I mean, isn't there a corresponding Kusto command to achieve streaming export, if SDK is allowing this but there is no command, it means probably the core feature exists but not exposed as a kusto command.